# JavaFX. Работа функции setShape()

Tags: java, javafx

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется следующий код:

```
Pane.setStyle("-fx-shape: \"M 0,0 200,0 180,100 0,100 Z\";");
```

Как реализовать результат полученный с помощью данной строчки, с помощью команды:

`Pane.setShape(...);`

Comment: Возможно стоит создать [`Polygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html) по этим четырём точкам по аналогии как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28027523/5812238) и уже его передать в `setShape`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SVGPath svgPath = new SVGPath();
svgPath.setContent( "M 0,0 200,0 180,100 0,100 Z" );
pane.setShape( svgPath );
```